# "Joint" random variable measurability finiteness condition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

> **Problem:** If $\{ X_i: \Omega \rightarrow R_i \}_1^n$ are measurable functions from $(\Omega, M_\Omega )$ into measurable spaces $(R_i,M_i)$, show that the joint map $(X_i)_i : \Omega \rightarrow \prod_1^n R_i $ is also measurable. $\prod R_i$ given product space.

My proof:

> Let $s$ denote the joint map. $\pi_i: \prod R_i \rightarrow R_i$ denote the projection. $s^{-1} ( \pi_i^{-1}(B_i) ) = X_i^{-1}(B_i)$ for measurable sets $B_i \in M_{i}$. Let $S:= \{ E \subseteq \prod R_i \, : \, s^{-1}(E) \in M_{\Omega} \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containg $\{ \pi^{-1}(B_i) \, : \, B_i \in M_i \}_i$, this by definition contains the $\sigma$ algebra of the product space $\prod R_i$.

In my proof, I did not use **finiteness.** Is my proof wrong, or is this statement true for arbitrary indicies (?)

EDIT: To be clear on why I asked this question. I have seen one defines the joint distribution of a *finite collection* of random variable, $(X_i)$, by 
$$ P_{(X_i)}(E)= P((X_i)^{-1}(E)) $$ 
where $E \subseteq \prod R_i$. Then there is nothing wrong about defining it for arbitrary product? I am thinking this is because one cannot generalize the notion of "independence".

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, I have two questions, (i) The LHS of your expression is in $[0,1]$ but the RHS is an intersection of sets. What do you mean here? (ii) By definition of product space, its $\sigma$ algebra is generated by $\{ \pi_i^{-1}(E_i) : E_i \in M_i \} $ . I have shown that $s$ have measurable inverses on this set, hence the $\sigma$-algebra generated by it. I don't think there is any problem with countability.(?) I think measurability of $s$ is fine, the problem may be with how to define a measure on product space, which I guess is what you are trying to say(?)

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, whats wrong with my point (ii)? $X$ is measurable as long as it is on a generating set.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, I don't think any of these contradicts my point, I think Eric below has already pointed out.

Comment: I mean the proof needs slight modification if the product space is something like $(\prod\limits_{t\in T}R_t,\prod\limits_{t\in T}\mathscr{M}_t)$.

Comment: It is unclear to me how you are defining your product space now... what is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\prod R_i $ for you?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your proof is not grammatically correct enough to call it "correct" or not.  But the idea is correct, and works regardless of the index set of the product (so finiteness is indeed irrelevant).  To check that $s$ is measurable, you just have to check that $s^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(B))$ is measurable for any measurable subset $B\subset R_i$.  This is true because $s^{-1}(\pi_i^{-1}(B))=X_i^{-1}(B)$, and therefore is measurable since $X_i$ is measurable.

Comment: so what is wrong in defining a push forward measure on aribtirary product of random variables, and defining it is a joint distribution? It is not seen in text books. I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: There is no problem with defining a joint distribution of infinitely many random variables.